# Python FastAPI docker image shows 404 page not found error

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda, fastapi

I am trying to dockerize a very simple (Hellow World) FastAPI and running it on AWS lambda as a container image. But I am only getting " 404 page not found error " when running docker image locally before pushing it to lambda.

I have just 3 files in my folder namely,

```
-dockerfle
-main.py
-requirements.txt
```

The content of dockerfile is

```
FROM amazon/aws-lambda-python:3.8
COPY . ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["main.handler"]
```

and the main.py has following code

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from mangum import Mangum 
app = FastAPI()
@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return{"message": "Hello World"}
handler = Mangum(app)
```

To build and run the container, I am using the below commands respectively

```
docker build -t try98 .
docker run -p 9000:8080 try98
```

After this when I visit my localhost:9000 I am only getting 404 page not found error. This is so simple but I am not what I am missing here. Can someone please help me here. Please. Thanks!

Below is my requirements.txt file

```
anyio==3.3.4
asgiref==3.4.1
click==8.0.3
colorama==0.4.4
fastapi==0.70.0
h11==0.12.0
idna==3.3
mangum==0.12.3
pydantic==1.8.2
sniffio==1.2.0
starlette==0.16.0
typing-extensions==3.10.0.2
uvicorn==0.15.0
```

Comment: 404 means that your request has reached the service but service was not able to look up requested resource. So you need to dig into your service routing and configuration.

Comment: @AlexeyR. can you a bit more specific here please? I am pretty new in this stuff. What actions I need to take? thanks

Comment: share your requirements.txt and what is `${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}`?

Comment: its from the official aws-lambda-python image. This acts as a variable and will hold the value of the root path. Normally in the above used image it is /var/task. Documentation below
https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/aws-lambda-python

Comment: I have updated the question with requirements.txt

Comment: were you hitting the your app from the link suggested in the docker site `curl  "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations"`

Comment: The main.py code which I shared above will work even if we visit or hit http://localhost:9000/. But it shows 404 page not found error.

Comment: Any update on this or it is still unsolved?